# Custom Tab Disappears on Click?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I have three tabs in `TabHost`.

Tab number 2 and 3 loads some data that will take around 4-5 seconds to load. When I click on any of these tabs, the tab disappeared until the data got loaded. Is there any reason for that? How can I handle this disappearing tab ?

One more thing that I should have to mention here is that I am creating Custom Tabs. But no rocket science in custom tabs just follow this links tutorial: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136.

Comment: what are you doing that is taking 4 to 5 seconds? Put your code up too.

Comment: When click on Tab, I am sending Http Get request to server and get the response json data from server. The received data will be stored in database and then displayed on the screen by loading it from database too. The whole functionality is working perfect but the Image used on custom tab got disappeared at the time of loading.

Comment: Are you doing this on the UI thread? If you are you might need to consider using AsyncTask to send request and fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks @blessenm for your support. I am not doing it on UI thread. The problem exists with in a code that I have copied from example.I have answered that one.

Comment: hmm good that you found ur self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have fixed the problem and find it out what I have done wrong.

The **tab_bg_selector.xml** file in the example is using **android:state_pressed="true"** and **android:state_focused="true"** item states which I have copy/paste in my code as it is. When the Tab is pressed the **android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"** will make the image transparent until the selected Image will display

So both these item are removed from the .xml file and now it working good :)